# Building dependency tree using apt-get is slow

Tags: software-installation

I just put a class 10 SD card and burned wheezy and updated everything. As time went on and I played around with settings I noticed that when I do a install now it can take **about 10 minutes to build the dependency tree**. This is every single time I need to install something trivial. The actual install time is fast and painless.

It driving me nuts? Why is it so slow? Does anybody know how to fix this?

- Don't run x desktop ever but still have it installed since it comes pre bundled.
- Model B 512 mem split 256/256.

Comment: care to elaborate regarding your memory split and installed software? do you still keep X11 and related stuff?

Comment: well, it might be helpful to remove x and dependencies, these have quite a tree. I don't have X, running headless with 16MB for video and building dependency tree takes about 3-4 seconds.

Comment: Thanks lenik. Is there a one liner to remove all the X junk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you  may remove X11 stuff with something along the lines of:

```
sudo apt-get remove x11-common
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

hope this helps =)

Answer (score 0):

**Delete a graphical interface and desktop env:**

> aptitude purge x11-common lxde gconf2-common gnome-desktop3-data

**Then a some, that left after deleting LXDE (no needs):**

> aptitude purge lxappearance lxde-common lxde-icon-theme lxinput
>   lxmenu-data lxpanel lxpanel-data lxpolkit lxrandr lxsession
>   lxsession-edit lxshortcut lxtask lxterminal

Comment: Will that solve the problem with the slow `apt-get`?